# PayPal email notification

Tags: paypal

I have received PayPal email notification about the products purchased by customers with product names and quantities. I see that there are some custom fields to pass custom parameters like size, color etc with individual products. I just want to know will these custom values return with PayPal email notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes these custom fields and quantity fields will be sent to your email.

Comment: I just wanted to know if I use on0 / on1 OR os0 / os1 to send some custom values, will PayPal notify me with these custom values when someone purchases products?